# Gulp watch keeps firing nonstop even though there aren't any change

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

Just like the title, I currently have a nasty problem with Gulp watch, that keeps on compiling my files even though there aren't any change made.

For instance, this is a piece of my 'watch' task

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(jsIn, ['babel']);
}
```

And my 'babel' task, just to compile my scripts and move them to dist folder

```
const jsIn = ['dev/scripts/*.js', 'dev/scripts/**/*.js'],
      jsOut = 'dist/scripts';

gulp.task('babel', function() {
gulp.src(jsIn)
    .pipe(babel())
        .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsOut))
    .pipe(connect.reload()); //yes I use gulp-connect to live reload my files.
});
```

When I run gulp watch it works normally, and then this keeps on happening

```
TRUONGs-MacBook-Pro:code sdsmnc$ gulp watch
[14:48:31] Using gulpfile /Volumes/SDSMNC_BU/2018/wildlife/code/gulpfile.js
[14:48:31] Starting 'watch'...
[14:48:31] Finished 'watch' after 14 ms
[14:48:32] Starting 'babel'...
[14:48:32] Finished 'babel' after 14 ms
[14:48:34] Starting 'babel'...
[14:48:34] Finished 'babel' after 1.95 ms
[14:48:34] Starting 'babel'...
[14:48:34] Finished 'babel' after 1.5 ms
[14:48:37] Starting 'babel'...
[14:48:37] Finished 'babel' after 1.18 ms
[14:48:39] Starting 'babel'...
[14:48:39] Finished 'babel' after 1.07 ms
[14:48:41] Starting 'babel'...
[14:48:41] Finished 'babel' after 1.03 ms
[14:48:42] Starting 'babel'...
[14:48:42] Finished 'babel' after 1.73 ms
[14:48:44] Starting 'babel'...
[14:48:44] Finished 'babel' after 1.04 ms
```

I practically use the same gulpfile.js for all of my projects, the old ones work fine, but somehow in this new project I get this problem. I tried to delete the node_modules folder and reinstall all the dependencies, even use the node_modules of my old projects but can't fix the problem.

Any help please...?